# how to print variable in side Table Header in Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```sql
create or alter proc printThisAsTableHeader
    @n as int
    as
    begin
        select 'values' as '@n is good'
    end
go

exec printThisAsTableHeader 2
```

the above code's output is:

| @n is good |
| --- |
| values |

I want `@n` should be replaced with its value.
I try many ways like `format, concat, convert, cast`, and `concatenation operator` as well, but unable to do that.

objective:
I just want to make a procedure that tacks an int parameter `@n`
and print nth highest salary.
`n=7`

| 7th highest salary |
| --- |
| salary value |

Comment: SQL isn't a scripting language, `'@n'` means the **literal string value** `'@n'` not the literal string value of the value stored within `@n`. The only way you would be able to do this would be with dynamic SQL. *Why* however, do you want to do this? This smells like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in my comment, this has a strong smell of an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). The above doesn't appear to actually achieve anything on it's own, so you're clearly trying to solve a different problem, that very likely doesn't even need dynamic SQL.

If you "must" (which I doubt) do this, then you you can achieve this like below:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROC dbo.printThisAsTableHeader @n int AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX) = N'SELECT ''values'' AS ' + QUOTENAME(CONCAT(@n,N' is good')) + N';'
    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
END;
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3551bbbcd1f580d93df4f7433d4e706b)

Comment: hay can you tell me what **N** does in  N' SQL query'. thanks in advance.